# Trying to Make an Apex Class Invocable so it can be used in skuid or list views

Tags: apex, invocable-method

```
public without sharing class trac_SetFieldsOnLockedOppExt {

private final Opportunity lockedOpp;

// The extension constructor initializes the private member
// variable mysObject by using the getRecord method from the standard
// controller.
public trac_SetFieldsOnLockedOppExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.lockedOpp = (Opportunity) stdController.getRecord();
    if( this.lockedOpp.IsClosed ) {
        ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'The current opportunity has been closed and cannot be modified.') );
    }
}

public PageReference saveLockedRecord() {
    PageReference pr = null;
    if( !lockedOpp.IsClosed ) {  
        update new Opportunity(
            Id = lockedOpp.Id,
            CloseDate = lockedOpp.CloseDate,
            Gate__c = lockedOpp.Gate__c,
            Annual_Web_SalesOpp__c = lockedOpp.Annual_Web_SalesOpp__c,
            Estimated_Signature_Date__c = lockedOpp.Estimated_Signature_Date__c,
            Stage_Qualifier__c = lockedOpp.Stage_Qualifier__c,
            Current_Affiliate_Annual_Sales_Revenue__c = lockedOpp.Current_Affiliate_Annual_Sales_Revenue__c,
            Percent_to_CJ__c = lockedOpp.Percent_to_CJ__c,
            Think_Big_Number__c = lockedOpp.Think_Big_Number__c
        );
        pr = new PageReference( '/' + lockedOpp.Id );
        pr.setRedirect( true );
    }
    return pr;
}
```

}

I was told I needed to make the above class invocable so that the button/visualforce/field set it is associated with can be used within Skuid, or standard salesforce list view.  The class updates fields on a locked opp.

Comment: were you able to accomplish this? I'm also trying to make a PageReference an InvocableMethod but the InvocableMethod cannot return this type.

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to contain **one** static method with the `InvocableMethod` annotation:

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Save Locked Record')
public static void saveLockedRecord()
{
    // your code
}
```